# How to slice JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

How to slice a JSON object in Python I have a JSON object which looks like:

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "b648e43a-6fd8-4b70-9981-28942473e0c3",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "etag": "W/\"1c08986f-3337-4c06-815e-aab31b4b196d\"",
      "location": "eastus",
      "tags": {
        "type": "aks-slb-managed-outbound-ip"
      },
      "zones": [
        "2",
        "1",
        "3"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "resourceGuid": "3bd20fd5-ffa3-4321-8309-354c252bec22",
        "ipAddress": "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx",
        "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 30,
        "ipTags": [],
        "ipConfiguration": {
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Regional"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "kubernetes-a40f77cc30dd047928d4e7fdf3c20a12",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "etag": "W/\"057c51ec-33a8-4bb6-9e02-50146f55b66c\"",
      "location": "eastus",
      "tags": {
        "kubernetes-cluster-name": "kubernetes",
        "service": "kube-system/ingress-nginx-public-controller"
      },
      "zones": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "resourceGuid": "ab07866e-19c1-4542-ab46-27306b7e7652",
        "ipAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
        "ipTags": [],
        "ipConfiguration": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Regional"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get `"ipConfiguration"` block. I tried changing the JSON block in Python dict and look for key value pair but `"ipConfiguration"` block is deep inside another dict. Can somebody help in figuring out how to get out `"ipConfiguration"` block data into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have stored your json data in a file & tried to get all ipConfiguration's id in a variable. Please find the code snippet for the same.

Code :-

```
import json

ipConfiguration_ids = []
with open('sample.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_dict = json.loads(json_file.read())
    for value in json_dict['value']:
        ipConfiguration_ids.append(
            value['properties']['ipConfiguration']['id'])
print(ipConfiguration_ids)
```

Output:-

```
['xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx']
```